# Remove duplicate within column depending on 2 lists in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups NAME          LETTER
G1     Canis_lupus   A
G1     Canis_lupus   B
G1     Canis_lupus   F
G1     Cattus_cattus C
G1     Cattus_cattus C
G2     Canis_lupus   C
G2     Zebra_fish    A
G2     Zebra_fish    D
G2     Zebra-fish    B
G2     Cattus_cattus D
G2     Cattus_cattus E
```

and the idea is that I would like within `Groups` to keep only two duplicated `NAME` where `LETTER` is within the `list1=['A','B','C']` and `list2=['D','E','F']`

When there is for instance duplicate having `A` and `B`, I keep the `A` in the alphabet order

In the example I should then get :

```
 Groups NAME          LETTER
G1     Canis_lupus   A
G1     Canis_lupus   F
G1     Cattus_cattus C
G2     Canis_lupus   C
G2     Zebra_fish    A
G2     Zebra_fish    D
G2     Cattus_cattus D
```

Here is tha dataframe

```
{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G1', 5: 'G2', 6: 'G2', 7: 'G2', 8: 'G2', 9: 'G2', 10: 'G2'}, 'NAME': {0: 'Canis_lupus', 1: 'Canis_lupus', 2: 'Canis_lupus', 3: 'Cattus_cattus', 4: 'Cattus_cattus', 5: 'Canis_lupus', 6: 'Zebra_fish', 7: 'Zebra_fish', 8: 'Zebra-fish', 9: 'Cattus_cattus', 10: 'Cattus_cattus'}, 'LETTER': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'F', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 6: 'A', 7: 'D', 8: 'B', 9: 'D', 10: 'E'}}
```

Comment: is there a typo in the 3rd from last row? ```Zebra-fish``` should be ```Zebra_fish``` ?

Comment: Why are `G1     Canis_lupus   F` and `G2     Zebra_fish    D` in the result set?

Answer (score 1):

Idea is first sorting by `LETTER` if necessary and then filter by both lists with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
#sorting per groups
df = df.sort_values(['Groups','LETTER'])

#sorting by one column
#df = df.sort_values('LETTER')


list1=['A','B','C'] 
list2=['D','E','F']
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['LETTER'].isin(list1)].drop_duplicates(['Groups','NAME'])
df2 = df[df['LETTER'].isin(list2)].drop_duplicates(['Groups','NAME'])


df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index(ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  Groups           NAME LETTER
0     G1    Canis_lupus      A
1     G1    Canis_lupus      F
2     G1  Cattus_cattus      C
3     G2    Canis_lupus      C
4     G2     Zebra_fish      A
5     G2     Zebra_fish      D
6     G2  Cattus_cattus      D
```

Idea with mapping values to new column with merge dictionaries, similar like another solution, only also removed rows if no match both `list`s by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), last remove helper column and sorting:

```
d = {**dict.fromkeys(list1, 'a'),
     **dict.fromkeys(list2, 'b')}


df = (df.assign(new = df.LETTER.map(d))
        .dropna(subset=['new'])
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['Groups', 'NAME', 'new'])
        .sort_index(ignore_index=True)
        .drop('new', 1)
        )

print (df)
  Groups           NAME LETTER
0     G1    Canis_lupus      A
1     G1    Canis_lupus      F
2     G1  Cattus_cattus      C
3     G2    Canis_lupus      C
4     G2     Zebra_fish      A
5     G2     Zebra_fish      D
6     G2  Cattus_cattus      D
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `list_id` column to identify which list a particular letter belongs to. Then just drop the duplicates using the `subset` parameter.

```
condlist = [df.LETTER.isin(list1),
            df.LETTER.isin(list2)]

choicelist = [
    'list1',
    'list2'
]

df['list_id'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
df = df.sort_values('LETTER').drop_duplicates(
    subset=['Groups', 'NAME', 'list_id']).drop('list_id', 1).sort_values(['Groups', 'NAME'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Groups           NAME LETTER
0     G1    Canis_lupus      A
2     G1    Canis_lupus      F
3     G1  Cattus_cattus      C
5     G2    Canis_lupus      C
9     G2  Cattus_cattus      D
6     G2     Zebra_fish      A
7     G2     Zebra_fish      D
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to match the output in the question.

Comment: @HenryEcker - Missing last sorting

Comment: I initially sorted based on the `LETTER` column as it was mentioned in the question that he wants to keep the top 2 duplicated sorted alphabetically. Forgot to add the last sorting. @HenryEcker will do that in a min.